# Copy a file to the build directory after compiling project with Qt

Tags: qmake

I have a file "settings.ini" which needs to reside next to the Qt executable.

I can add a custom build step for this in Qt Creator which calls something like this:

```
copy %{sourceDir}/settings.ini %{buildDir}/settings.ini
```

This works great so far, but I'd like to include this in the *.pro file so I can put this up in our SVN too.

How can I do this using qmake/.pro-files only?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably want to use the [`INSTALLS` keyword](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmake-environment-reference.html#installs) in QMake.  It will require you to run `make install` after your build, but it does work cross-platform.

```
install_it.path = %{buildDir}
install_it.files += %{sourceDir}/settings.ini

INSTALLS += install_it
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen lots of these. But I guess this won't work in Qt Creator when compiling, for example.

Comment: @Strayer Why won't it work?  Just add another build step, `make install`.  I have several working examples of it working in Qt Creator on my machine right now.

Comment: Hmm, well, in that case sorry for my comment ;) I'll try this the next time I'm working on the project!

Comment: I'm trying to get it to work, but `make install` says me: `Nothing to be done for 'install'`. What could be wrong?

Comment: @DmitryFrank Without seeing what your .pro file looks like, it is hard to say.  My guess is that the file you are trying to install does not exist at the time you run qmake.  This [Qt Centre question](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/35817-qmake-INSTALLS-variable-not-working-as-expected) might help.

Comment: @jwernerny sorry I haven't specified it here, but I already asked my own question and got the answer that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066593/copy-a-file-to-build-directory-after-compiling-project-with-qt . Thank you. Here, I just thought that `%{buildDir}` and `%{sourceDir}` are already defined by Qt.

Comment: Is there a simple way to copy all the files in a directory instead of listing them all out one by one?

Comment: @djsosofresh I have not done it with using `make install`, but it can be done as suggested by Paglian's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36438618/447438).

Comment: I don't want the *just another build step, `make install`*.

Comment: This approach seems to be the QMake standard way, but this adds extra steps for someone who like to build the project. so, my project couldn't be built out of the box. Have you any further point about this?

Answer (score 18):

To copy `%{sourceDir}/settings.ini` to the build directory **without** requiring to call `make install` use:

```
copydata.commands = $(COPY_DIR) $$PWD/settings.ini $$OUT_PWD
first.depends = $(first) copydata
export(first.depends)
export(copydata.commands)
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += first copydata
```

`$$PWD` is the path of current `.pro` file. If your `settings.ini` file is not located in the same directory than the project file, then use something like `$$PWD/more_dirs_here/settings.ini`

**Note**: I found this solution [here](http://dragly.org/2013/11/05/copying-data-files-to-the-build-directory-when-working-with-qmake/). I recommend to read the whole article as it explains how it works.

Comment: This appears to have the rather nasty habit under Windows of ending up with the command `xcopy /s /q /y /i c:/source/file c:/dest/file` - `xcopy` does *not* like the forward slashes since it seems to treat them as switches leading to a "incorrect number of args" error.

Comment: use `copydata.commands = $(COPY_DIR) $$shell_path($$PWD/settings.ini) $$shell_path($$OUT_PWD)` to avoid the slash problem under windows

Comment: How about multiple files? e.g: 1.ini and 2.ini

Comment: @SuB I just added an answer to address this. Basically, add another variable like `copydata` and repeat the same approach.

Answer (score 2):

for osx bundles you can handle it this way
see [Resource files in OS X bundle](https://wiki.qt.io/Resource_files_in_OS_X_bundle)

add this to you project file:

```
APP_QML_FILES.files = path/to/file1.qml path/to/file2.qml
APP_QML_FILES.path = Contents/Resources
QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += APP_QML_FILES
```

this example copies the files to Contents/Resources

Comment: this can't detect changes of `file2.qml`

Answer (score 0):

Compatible with Windows and Mac OSX Dev environments:

Change {AppName} to respective application name

```
# Define mac/windows specific target dirs
TARGETDIR = ''
macx {
  TARGETDIR      += $$OUT_PWD/{AppName}.app/Contents/MacOS/
}
else {
  TARGETDIR      += $$OUT_PWD
}

# Directories do not exist for the first build
# Without mkdata, build is successful after 5 tries. To avoid, use mkdata
mkdata.commands = $(MKDIR) $${TARGETDIR}
copydata.commands = $(COPY_FILE) $$PWD/settings.ini $${TARGETDIR}
first.depends = $(first) mkdata copydata
export(first.depends)
export(mkdata.commands)
export(copydata.commands)
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += first mkdata copydata
```

Happy to add Unix support if someone posts Unix solution in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking to copy multiple files or directories: Expanding on Paglian's answer, I found that adding another variable with commands worked.

```
copyconfig.commands = $(COPY_DIR) $$shell_path($$PWD\config) $$shell_path($$DESTDIR\config)
copystyle.commands = $(COPY_DIR) $$shell_path($$PWD\style) $$shell_path($$DESTDIR\style)
first.depends = $(first) copyconfig copystyle
export(first.depends)
export(copyconfig.commands)
export(copystyle.commands)
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += first copyconfig copystyle
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a python script where I do the copy of the files.

Then in the .pro file I add the following line:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += python $$PWD/copy_requirements.py $$PWD $$OUT_PWD
```

I pass the source directory with `$$PWD` and the build directory with `$$OUT_PWD`.

The python `copy_requirements.py` script then uses these variables to copy the files needed from the source directory to the build directory. This is executed after the code compilation.

This works on windows / linux. According to [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-variable-reference.html) this doesn't work on Xcode projects.