# Copy a file to build directory after compiling project with Qt

Tags: qt, qmake

I have seen several suggestions, but nothing really worked for me as I want. I just need to copy a file to the desired destination directory.

Say, for example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795397/copy-a-file-to-the-build-directory-after-compiling-project-with-qt):

```
install_it.path = %{buildDir}
install_it.files += %{sourceDir}/settings.ini

INSTALLS += install_it
```

Variables `%{buildDir}` and `%{sourceDir}` should be defined, to make this work. Ok, there's no problem with `%{sourceDir}`: it is just `.`. But how can I get `%{buildDir}`?

**EDIT1**

Say, I have a project `my_project` here:

`/path/to/my_project`

So, release build path is this: `/path/to/my_project-build-Desktop-release`,

debug build path is this: `/path/to/my_project-build-Desktop-debug`

I have files to be copied to destination directory here: `/path/to/my_project/copy_to_install_dir`

So, I want all files from `/path/to/my_project/copy_to_install_dir` to be copied to `/path/to/my_project-build-Desktop-release` when I do release build. And, the same way for debug build.

I can't find variable which contain full destination path, i.e. `/path/to/my_project-build-Desktop-release` for debug build.

Just in case: I use Windows, but anyway I'm looking for crossplatform solution.

**EDIT2**

Exact solution, for future readers:

```
install_it.path = $$OUT_PWD
install_it.files = copy_to_install_dir/*

INSTALLS += \
    install_it
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is what we are using in QtSerialPort:

```
target_headers.files  = $$PUBLIC_HEADERS
target_headers.path   = $$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]/QtSerialPort
INSTALLS              += target_headers

mkspecs_features.files    = $$QTSERIALPORT_PROJECT_ROOT/src/serialport/qt4support/serialport.prf
mkspecs_features.path     = $$[QT_INSTALL_DATA]/mkspecs/features
INSTALLS                  += mkspecs_features
```

Basically, you set the files and path for the target, and then append that into the `INSTALLS` variable. What you still need is the `$$OUT_PWD` variable which we are also using extensively in `QtSerialPort`. That will provide you the root of the build directory.

It is one of those undocumented qmake features, but it is very useful.

Also, for the source directory in general at large, you should not assume "." and so forth because that may be different as you run through a wrapper application in which the "." will point to that and not what you expect: the qmake source project root. In those cases, it is safer to use the `PWD` variable which points to the source as opposed `OUT_PWD` which points to the build folder.

Just to give a rough example about the difference o those two variables with a real world scenario, here you can find what we are doing in QtSerialPort:

```
system("echo QTSERIALPORT_PROJECT_ROOT = $$PWD >> $$OUT_PWD/.qmake.cache")
system("echo QTSERIALPORT_BUILD_ROOT = $$OUT_PWD >> $$OUT_PWD/.qmake.cache")
```

where the former is the root for the source project, and the latter for the build directory. They may be the same, but in many cases they are not, e.g. when building through QtCreator just for one of those.

Comment: This does the thing only with `make install`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36438513/3129752 for doing it at `make`.

Comment: Thanks! Finally managed to make it work (I had configured `make install` already). Just a note: `system("echo ..")` doesn't work for me, I used `message()` instead of.

Answer (score 48):

The selected answer is correct but it requires to call `make install`, which in my opinion is annoying or error prone. Instead, to copy files to the build directory use:

```
copydata.commands = $(COPY_DIR) $$PWD/required_files $$OUT_PWD
first.depends = $(first) copydata
export(first.depends)
export(copydata.commands)
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += first copydata
```

Where `required_files` must be replaced with your correct path. `$$PWD` is the path of current `.pro` file, you might not require this.

**Note**: I found this solution [here](https://dragly.org/2013/11/05/copying-data-files-to-the-build-directory-when-working-with-qmake/). I recommend to read the whole article as it explains how it works.

Comment: Is it possible to make a condition that would copy files/folders inside the `Mybinary.app/Contents/MacOS` on Mac?

Comment: @alexandernst I think what you could do is to define a variable for the output dir according your OS. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html#scopes-and-conditions

Comment: the article 404 not found

Comment: @Paglian, Thank you for useful answer.

Comment: need quotes for path with spaces: $$PWD/required_files -> \"$$PWD/required_files\". And quotes for out directory

Answer (score 22):

Having had the pleasure of wasting a few hours with this, i thought i'd share my findings on the matter. This in a modified variant of Paglian's method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36438513/6530466). Since i'm using windows (without mingw) that method doesn't work. So here is the modified variant:

```
# using shell_path() to correct path depending on platform
# escaping quotes and backslashes for file paths
copydata.commands = $(COPY_FILE) \"$$shell_path($$PWD\\archive.png)\" \"$$shell_path($$OUT_PWD)\"
first.depends = $(first) copydata
export(first.depends)
export(copydata.commands)
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += first copydata
```

Since this makes it cross platform you could of course also use this method in Linux, MacOS or what have you. Do note that i'm copying a single file, so instead of `$(COPY_DIR)` i'm using `$(COPY_FILE)`. Adapt as needed.

---

If you want the file(s) copied to the exact path of where the binary ends up (since the binary will end up in a subfolder of $$OUT_PWD (*debug* or *release*, at least when building with Qt Creator with MSVC 14/cdb.exe/Code::Blocks Makefiles configuration) you need this:

```
# adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2581068
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    VARIANT = debug
} else {
    VARIANT = release
}
```

Beware that even though the binary ends up in a subfolder, QtCreator executes the binary from `$$OUT_PWD`, so it expects to find file resources in `$$OUT_PWD`, and NOT the *debug* subdir. That means you for example can't do `QIcon("archive.png")` and expect it to find it besides the executable.

This is of course easy to remedy by doing:

```
QDir exeDir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
QIcon qIcon(exeDir.filePath("archive.png"));
```

IF you decide this is what you want, you obviously need to edit the last argument of `$$(COPY_FILE)` (in .pro) like this: `\"$$shell_path($$OUT_PWD)\\$$VARIANT\"`

---

One other thing to note is that (in my case anyway) Qt Creator (4.0.1) doesn't always build the .pro file, since it's not detecting any changes in the configuration, so to have the above changes reflected in the Makefile (and thus run when you build your project) you have to actually build the .pro manually by running `Build->run qmake` from the application menu. To ensure everything goes smooth, look as the compile output by hitting Alt+4 (on Windows anyway).

Comment: where did you find out about `COPY_FILE` or `COPY_DIR` from? In qt creator help mode, the qmake documentation had no hit for the word "copy" (other than copyright...) for me. I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324061/ but only after I read in your post that these exist.

Comment: To be honest, i just found them when tracking down what was happening behind the scenes. Can't remember the specifics of it, but i did manage to find this after the fact: https://wiki.qt.io/Undocumented_QMake

Comment: How to copy all files in a subdir? I tried with `$$PWD\\subdir\\*` in the first row, but it gives me error.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the following QMake code helps as a starting point. It copies the recently built binary to some other directory "TARGET_DEST":

```
TARGET_SRC  = $${_PRO_FILE_PWD_}
TARGET_DEST = $${PWD}/src

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    TARGET_SRC = $${TARGET_SRC}/debug
} else {
    TARGET_SRC = $${TARGET_SRC}/release
}

TARGET_SRC   = $${TARGET_SRC}/$${TARGET}
TARGET_DEST  = $${TARGET_DEST}/$${TARGET}

linux-g++{
    if( equals(TEMPLATE, app) || equals(TEMPLATE, vcapp) ){
        # nothing to do here
    }
    if( equals(TEMPLATE, lib) || equals(TEMPLATE, vclib) ){
        TARGET_SRC   = $${TARGET_SRC}.so
        TARGET_DEST  = $${TARGET_DEST}.so
    }
    QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(cp $${TARGET_SRC} $${TARGET_DEST}$$escape_expand(\n\t))
}

win32 {
    if( equals(TEMPLATE, app) || equals(TEMPLATE, vcapp) ){
        TARGET_SRC   = $${TARGET_SRC}.exe
        TARGET_DEST  = $${TARGET_DEST}.exe
    }
    if( equals(TEMPLATE, lib) || equals(TEMPLATE, vclib) ){
        TARGET_SRC   = $${TARGET_SRC}.dll
        TARGET_DEST  = $${TARGET_DEST}.dll
    }
    TARGET_SRC  ~= s,/,\\,g # fix slashes 
    TARGET_DEST ~= s,/,\\,g # fix slashes
    QMAKE_POST_LINK +=$$quote(cmd /c copy /y $${TARGET_SRC} $${TARGET_DEST}$$escape_expand(\n\t))
}

message("[INFO] Will copy $${TARGET_SRC} to $${TARGET_DEST}")
```

Comment: Upvoted for using `QMAKE_POST_LINK` rather than `INSTALLS` or `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use DESTDIR and PWD qmake variables or OUT_PWD: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qmake/qmake-variable-reference.html#destdir

Comment: When I'm not sure for qmake variables, I use message : message($$OUT_PWD). It's usefull

Answer (score 0):

This in a modified variant of PKSWE's method.

```
dummyTarget.commands = @echo After building copy..
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += dummyTarget
PRE_TARGETDEPS += dummyTarget

toolsCopy.commands = $(COPY_DIR) $$shell_path($$PWD/copyDir/*) $$shell_path($$DESTDIR)
dummyTarget.depends += toolsCopy
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += toolsCopy

toolsCopyLib.commands = $(COPY_FILE) $$shell_path($$PWD/setting.ini) $$shell_path($${DESTDIR})
dummyTarget.depends += toolsCopyLib
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += toolsCopyLib
```

But, I have an other question, **how to copy if changed?** Since it takes too much time when it doesn't need to copy.