# In mingw,qmake copy_dir is always error

Tags: qt, qmake

I want to copy some qml to my build directory.
In `.pro`, I add:

```
copydata.commands = $(COPY_DIR) \"$$PWD/plugins\" \"$$DESTDIR/plugins\"
```

But when I build the project, the `copydata` is error.
The error message is :

> xcopy /s /q /y /i
>   "E:/myproject/src/plugins"
>   "E:/myproject/bin/debug/plugins"
>   Invalid number of parameters

But ,I copy the command to cmd ,it's all right.

Does anyone knows what the wrong is ？

Comment: Windows might get confused by those forward slashes. Try backslashes in all cases.

Comment: Also, the way you cited your example error, you don't seem to need quote marks. Try it without those quote marks.

Comment: Yes，you're right. I replaced forward slashes to backslashes manually, it works,
But , in the $$PWD, always forward slashes, how can I change them?
And , the quote is necessary

Comment: I got it. I should use qmake replace functions. Thank you.

Comment: Good find, those replace functions. I'll enter this in as an actual answer. Would love for you to mark it answered.

Comment: I like using the $$clean_path() method so that I maintain cross platform capability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows might get confused by those forward slashes. Try backslashes in all cases.

Answer (score 6):

I got it!
Thank you, macetw, you point the way.

The correct code should be:

```
copydata.commands = $(COPY_DIR) $$shell_path($$PWD/plugins) $$shell_path($$DESTDIR/plugins)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution that works on Linux and Windows with Qt 4.8 and higher:

```
win32 {
    COPY_FROM_PATH=$$shell_path($$PWD/plugins)
    COPY_TO_PATH=$$shell_path($$DESTDIR/plugins)
}
else {
    COPY_FROM_PATH=$$PWD/plugins
    COPY_TO_PATH=$$DESTDIR/plugins
}

copydata.commands = $(COPY_DIR) $$COPY_FROM_PATH $$COPY_TO_PATH
first.depends = $(first) copydata

export(first.depends)
export(copydata.commands)

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += first copydata
```

Useful links:

- https://forum.qt.io/topic/47029/copy-dir-for-build-dir
- https://forum.qt.io/topic/53817/solved-copy-a-directory-recursively-by-qmake
- [Where are variables such as $(MKDIR) and $(COPY_DIR) defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324061/where-are-variables-such-as-mkdir-and-copy-dir-defined)
- https://wiki.qt.io/Undocumented_QMake