# Delete directory contents with qmake during build

Tags: qt, qt4, qmake, del

I would like QMAKE_CLEAN to empty/delete a data directory in my build directory. I already have it clear out all of the DLLs from the build directory like so:

```
win32: {
    Debug: {
        QMAKE_CLEAN += $$slasher("$${OUT_PWD}/debug/*.dll")
    } else {
        QMAKE_CLEAN += $$slasher("$${OUT_PWD}/release/*.dll")
    }
}
```

and that works just fine.

However, when I try to delete the entire contents of a directory like so:

```
QMAKE_CLEAN += $$slasher("Q:/stuff/*.*")
```

It fails to work. I looked in the Compile Output window and saw this text:

```
Q:\stuff\*.*, Are you sure (Y/N)?
```

Why does this prompt show up and how can I get past it?

FYI, The `slasher' function is just a convenience function to turn forward slashes to backslashes on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the Windows `del` command requires a prompt when using the global wildcard. You can suppress this prompt by adding the `/Q` flag to the delete call in windows like this:

```
QMAKE_CLEAN += "$$slasher("Q:/stuff/*.*") /Q"
```

It's sketchy at best, but it works. If anyone knows another way in Qt4, I'd be happy to hear it.

**Edit**
I just found out that if you invoke this syntax twice in the PRO file, the compiler will complain. My workaround is to move the `/Q` to the very end of the PRO file in its own `QMAKE_CLEAN` call. It benignly confuses qmake by causing an additional call to `del /Q` during `clean`, but appears to work as expected.

For example...

```
QMAKE_CLEAN += "$$slasher("Q:/stuff1/*.*")"
QMAKE_CLEAN += "$$slasher("Q:/stuff2/*.*")"
QMAKE_CLEAN += /Q
```

...will delete the entire contents of `stuff1` and `stuff2`.

Comment: Does not seem to work in Qt 5. The /Q is automatically changed to \Q. I am unsure how to prevent that automatic replacement.

Comment: @Zitrax For Qt5 you might have better luck with QMAKE_DEL_TREE. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42239037/1666676

Comment: @Zitrax Did you ever figure this out? I just upgraded a project to qt5 and am having the same problem. Although `QMAKE_DEL_TREE` does work as a post-link, it fails when the directory doesn't exist yet.