# Application crash with TERMINATED

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, gcc, ldd

I have one application made in QT, and sometimes when I start it, occurre an inexpected TERMINATED error.
But If I retry sometimes, the application open normally.

```
ebonomo@ICCSW-044681NB /usr/local/app/bin$ ./myapp 
Terminado
ebonomo@ICCSW-044681NB /usr/local/app/bin$ ./myapp 
Terminado
ebonomo@ICCSW-044681NB /usr/local/app/bin$ ./myapp 
"Iniciando ...
.....
```

I created a *lib* folder in **app/lib** with all *libs* detected in **lddtree**. I changed too in *.bashrc* to set **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/app/lib/
```

But I can't get why this error. Could you help me? How can I get the cause? Is there any command to check it?

I already tried remove all in main method keeping only a debug message, and the error occurred yet.

I don't know more what can I do. :(

My environment is:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Qt 5.15.2
- Qt Creator 7.0.1
- Based on Qt 6.2.3 (GCC 10.3.1 20210422 (Red Hat 10.3.1-1), 64 bit)
- Built on Apr 26 2022 01:18:11
- From revision da16d778d5

**OBS:** I can reproduce the error with this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qFatal("Starting application");
}
```

My **.pro** is it:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2020-09-24T10:15:43
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui network svg
QT       += multimedia
QT       += multimediawidgets
QT       += 3drender
QT       += printsupport

CONFIG += ccache use_gold_linker precompile_header # Improve Build Speed
PRECOMPILED_HEADER = precompiled_header.h

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets quick

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH = $$PWD/ui/imports

TARGET = myapp
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs/qtmqtt
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/opencv4
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/imagerender/src
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs/fingerprint/Futronic/header


#Include static lib QT MQTT
equals(QT_VERSION, "5.15.2") {
    #message("Loading lib libQt5Mqtt for 5.15.2")
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/qtmqtt/5.15.2 -lQt5Mqtt
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,--rpath=$$PWD/libs/qtmqtt/5.15.2
}

equals(QT_VERSION, "5.15.1") {
    #message("Loading lib libQt5Mqtt for 5.15.1")
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/qtmqtt/5.15.1 -lQt5Mqtt
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,--rpath=$$PWD/libs/qtmqtt/5.15.1
}

LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/fingerprint/Futronic -lScanAPI
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,--rpath=$$PWD/libs/fingerprint/Futronic

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0
LIBS += -lopencv_core
LIBS += -lopencv_highgui
LIBS += -lopencv_imgproc
LIBS += -lopencv_features2d
LIBS += -lopencv_calib3d
LIBS += -lopencv_videoio
LIBS += -lopencv_imgcodecs
LIBS += -lrt

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
    # a lot of .cpp here

HEADERS += \
    constants.h 
    # a lot of .h here

FORMS +=

DISTFILES += \
    settings.ini

RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc \
    images/logos/logo.png

TRANSLATIONS += i18n/en.ts \
               i18n/es.ts \
               i18n/pt.ts

# From here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36438618
copydata.commands = $(COPY_DIR) $$PWD/settings.ini $$OUT_PWD
first.depends = $(first) copydata

export(first.depends)
export(copydata.commands)

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-unknown-pragmas # Ignore pragma region warnings
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += first copydata
```

Comment: You almost certainly have undefined behaviour somewhere in your code.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: Maybe you have some global / static variables that have some problem like static initialization order fiasco. I second the debug recommendation.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I put the example above

Comment: You are not sharing the code you explain. Your output has `"Iniciando ...
.....`, but there is nothing like that in the code you shared. Also, please do not use the long obsolete qmake. Switch to cmake.

Comment: `qFatal("Starting application");` isn't that supposed to terminate the application because of the fatal error?